# unable to display json content in backbone

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, backbone.js

everything is working well on my app, but when i manually add the objects in the browsers console, i'm getting the json model data in the Get but it doesn't render on the web page.

I'm calling a notes view in a list view to render into a UL.

This is my html Element

```
<html>

<head>

<title> Backbone Demo </title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>


<script type="text/template" id="library-template">
<h1> My Notes List </h1>
<ul class="mynotes"></ul>

</script>


<script type="text/template" id="mynote-template">
<div class="mynote-title"> </div>
<div class="mynote-content"</div>
</script>


</head>
<body>

<div id="container">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the Backbone View Script.

```
 window.LibraryView = Backbone.View.extend({
            tagName: 'section',
            className: 'mynotes',


           initialize: function() {
                  _.bindAll(this, 'render');
                  this.template = _.template($('#library-template').html());
                  this.collection.bind('reset', this.render);
           },

           render: function() {
                    var $mynotes,
                          collection = this.collection;

                    $(this.el).html(this.template({}));
                    $mynotes = this.$(".mynotes");
                    collection.each(function(mynote) {
                            var view = new LibraryMynoteview({
                                  model: mynote,
                                  collection: collection
                            });
                            $mynotes.append(view.render().edl);

                    });
                    return this;
           }

});
```

Comment: Can you show the format of your content? How is your json data look like?

Answer (score 1):

You should have posted your LibraryMynoteview as well. One thing I have found in your code is that your "mynote-template" does not contain any template tags.

```
<script type="text/template" id="mynote-template">
  <div class="mynote-title"> </div>
  <div class="mynote-content"</div>
</script>
```

This should be something like this:

```
<script type="text/template" id="mynote-template">
  <div class="mynote-title">{{title}}</div>
  <div class="mynote-content">{{content}}</div>
</script>
```

Could be that you are currently rendering empty div elements in your page. Another thing I saw was that you append some ".edl" to your notes (should be .el):

```
$mynotes.append(view.render().edl);
```

Not sure if this is only a typo. Last but not least your code requires the DOM to be ready. So make sure you init your view within:

```
$(function(){
  // init here
});
```